# While using Ajax model object are not being saved

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I have a model which is defined as follows in models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    Post_Name = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Comments_Post_Name')
    Comment_By = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Comment_By')
    Comment = models.CharField(max_length=100000000, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Post_Name.Post_Caption + " Commented By " + self.Comment_By.username
```

I want to change the 'Comment' using AJAX but it is not changing.
My AJAX view and Javascript are as follows are as follows.

```
def EditComment(request):
    ctx = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        New = Comments.objects.get(id=request.POST['Comment'])
        New.Comment = request.POST['Change']
        New.save()
        print(New.Comment)
        ctx = {'result': 'Done'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

And this is the script where AJAX is called.

```
function EditComment() {
        var str = document.getElementById('Comment_ID').value
        var saveChange = document.getElementById('message-text').innerHTML
        console.log(str)
        console.log(saveChange)
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{% url 'EditComment' %}",
                data: {
                    'Comment': str,
                    'Change': saveChange,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (rs) {
                    alert(rs.responseText);
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Also, in the terminal window The same comment object is printed which i want to edit...its just that the contents of it are not being edited.....I also saved the object after editing but still it doesn't save...

Any Solutions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error... I was passign wrong value in AJAX Data dictionary